# Eloquent sum parameters db issue

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a db table names clase_schedule, and 2 colums that are schedule_id and capMax, soy i want to get the total cap for each schedule, in sql it will be like this:

```
select schedule_id, sum(capMax) 
From ClaseSchedule 
Group By schedule_id
```

i've tryed to do it on eloquent and i'm not been able.

Comment: Have you checked your table name? I see you mention clase_schedule in your question, but ClaseSchedule in your code example. Notice the underscore in the middle.

Comment: yes, that is not the problem, the probles is to translate that into eloquent code

Comment: You should post your attempt code here :)

Comment: $plazas = ClaseSchedule::select('schedule_id', ClaseSchedule::sum('capMax'))->groupBy('schedule_id');

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
DB::table('ClaseSchedule')
   ->select(['schedule_id', DB::raw('SUM(capMax')])
   ->groupBy('schedule_id')->get();
```

In order to use MySQL aggregate function in Eloquent you need to use `DB::raw`

Or you can use `sum` like this

```
DB::table('ClaseSchedule')->sum('capMax')->groupBy('schedule_id')->get();
```

References:
https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates

Comment: i think this is the way , but now it throws me an error because it doesn't let me use DB::

Comment: you need to `use DB` in top of your file

Comment: We were missing the ->get(), solved with this, thnks